# got empty result in scraping a record

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

i made a progam to scrap attributes from single record from web but i am getting nothing in my variables below is what i tried. I am unable to understand where my logic is wrong

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://openlibrary.org/works/OL7960560W/Eyewitness?edition=ia%3Acowboy0000murd_y0x0"
global title
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,5)
items = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="workDetails"]')))
for item in items:
    title = item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'work-title').text

print("title = ",title)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in page_source you have saved. you have to wait for some time

```
#iterate the the list of elements if there are more than one elements
```

Answer (score 2):

I there are more than one elements with same class then be sure you are locating the right element.

```
Find the elements list
iterate the list
locate your required element
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here:

1. You are locating a wrong element.
   There is only 1 element matching `'//div[@class="workDetails"]'`.
2. Also, instead of `presence_of_all_elements_located` you should use `visibility_of_all_elements_located` there.
3. The `print("title = ",title)` should be done inside the `for` loop block. Otherwise it's content will be overwritten each loop iteration and only the last value will be finally printed.

The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://openlibrary.org/works/OL7960560W/Eyewitness?edition=ia%3Acowboy0000murd_y0x0"

driver.get(url)
titles = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.book .title>a')))
for title in titles:
    print(title.text)
```

The output is:

```
Eyewitness: Cowboy (Eyewitness Books)
Eyewitness: Horse (Eyewitness Books)
Eyewitness: Goya (Eyewitness Books)
```

I used CSS Selector, but XPath can be used as well here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of locating those elements, a bit more reliably:

```
[..]
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    [...]
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
url = "https://openlibrary.org/works/OL7960560W/Eyewitness?edition=ia%3Acowboy0000murd_y0x0e"
driver.get(url)

select_editions_number = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//select[@name="editions_length"]'))))
select_editions_number.select_by_visible_text("All")

items = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//table[@id="editions"]//div[@class="title"]/a')))
for i in items:
    print(i.text)
```

Result in terminal:

```
Eyewitness: Cowboy (Eyewitness Books)
Eyewitness: Horse (Eyewitness Books)
Eyewitness: Goya (Eyewitness Books)
Eyewitness: Seashore (Eyewitness Books)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can specify for an absoluted path by `/html/body/div[@class='workDetails']`, and use `polling2` module to request titles from `<table id="editions" class="editions-table editions-table--progressively-enhanced">`

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import polling2
...

items = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, /html/body/div[@class='workDetails']))) 
titles = polling2.poll(lambda: WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//table[@id="editions"]//div[@class="title"]/a'))), step=0.5, timeout=7)
```

I also recommend checking the `Wait` variants, so that you can use the more efficient method of short wait time or sleep, for example if you use **element_to_be_clickable** *Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it*. the element will not return a valid value, so you could extract it from the DOM without seeing it, for example **visibility_of_element_located** *An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible*.

- [Expected condition types](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions)
- [wait until element is present, visible and interactable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable)
- [polling for Selenium WebDriver elements](https://polling2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#polling-for-selenium-webdriver-elements)